# In nftables, is the verdict statement "accept" final or not?

Tags: nftables

I have problems understanding verdict statements in `nftables`. From `man nft`, or from [here](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html#lbCU), shortly below the heading "Verdict statement", we read the following:

> accept and drop are absolute verdicts --- they terminate ruleset evaluation immediately.

but then, in the next sentence (emphasizing mine):

> accept: Terminate ruleset evaluation and accept the packet. **The packet can still be dropped later by another hook** [...]

I can't help but isn't that a contradiction in itself? Which one is true? Does `accept` terminate ruleset evaluation immediately, or does it not? Only one of the statements cited can be true.

I am especially interested in the behavior of `accept` statements in `ingress` hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what they mean is that the `accept` will end that specific hook, but another may stop it. For example, [looking at this illustration](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Netfilter_hooks), if the **Forward Hook** were to `accept`, but then the **Postrouting Hook** were to `drop`, that would satisfy your latter quote because it is "another hook."

(This is speculation because I only have experience in `ipchains/iptables` but it looks similar enough and IIRC worked in a similar manner.)

Comment: and actually more: nftables can use multiple chains in the same hook. So there can be two chains hooking in ingress filter (on the same device) with one chain accepting and one dropping. Whatever the order the fate of the packet is a logical AND: (accept and drop) = drop

Comment: @A.B Tank you very much, and +1 for caring about it, but: Are you absolutely sure? From reading `man nft`, I got the impression that the chain with the higher `priority` determines the fate of the packet in such cases. Does your statement about the logical AND relate only to chains with the same priority?

Comment: @Binarus the best way for you to become sure is to do an experiment about it, possibly with counters or with nftrace. My AND is valid with chains with the same priority or not: it's just applying common sense about the results. But you should always avoid chains with same priority or other effects (mangling packets etc) are undefined because order is undefined.

Comment: OK, thanks, +1 and accepted. The link to the illustration confirms your point of view, notably because the illustration is on the netfilter.org website, not somewhere else. Some tests also seem to confirm your statement, although we can't test all possible combinations (of hooks) which could occur.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, accept is final decision in iptables and nftables.

But...for current table only.

https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/c3965.html

> As soon as the match specification for a packet has been fully
> satisfied, and we specify ACCEPT as the target, the rule is accepted
> and will **not continue traversing the current chain or any other ones
> in the same table**. Note however, that a packet that was accepted in
> one chain might still travel through chains within other tables, and
> could still be dropped there.

The same logic is for nftables.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. However, I am still mistrustful somehow. I have read more that one time that `iptables` and `nftables` are different beasts, and that their architecture differs fundamentally. Do you have a reference which describes the analogies?

Comment: For short answer read about accept in VERDICT STATEMENT https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html  I will add information to the answer later.

Comment: OK, thanks again, and +1. Sad that I can't share the reputation, but I'll give the credits to @Aaron D. Marasco because he was the first who answered and gave the link to the illustration which confirms his point of view, notably because it's on the netfilter.org website.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed the following piece of information the first time, or maybe the netfilter people have updated the documentation. However, I guess it's worth to add even given the other answers. From [the docs](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains) (emphasis mine):

> If a packet is accepted and there is another chain, bearing **the same hook type and with a later priority, then the packet will subsequently traverse this other chain.** Hence, **an accept verdict** - be it by way of a rule or the default chain policy - **isn't necessarily final.** However, **the same is not true of packets that are subjected to a drop verdict. Instead, drops take immediate effect, with no further rules or chains being evaluated.**

For me, this doesn't leave any questions open. The only thing that perhaps could be explained in addition is the slightly weird usage of the term "priority":

A lower priority number (e.g. -400 vs. -300) means a *higher* priority in the sense that the chain / hook with the lower priority number will be evaluated first. Therefore, this hook could do everything with the packet, including preventing other hooks from processing it. In natural language, we probably would call this the highest priority (but please note that I could be plain wrong with that because I am a non-native speaker).

But a higher priority number (e.g. 300 vs. -300) can also mean a *higher* priority in the sense that the chain / hook with the higher priority number can override an "accept" verdict that a chain / hook with a lower priority number has made.

It has taken me a while to get that. It probably would be better to dump the term "priority" in that context and replace it by something like "time of evaluation" or something far better that native speakers can think of.